# EF linq Find in list where objectA.prop1 is any of objectB.prop2

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, contains, any

I have some question about a linq query I cannot manage to do. It's matter of finding objects

Consider the List (ListA), where i want to select all rows where the value of field F20 is in a list (ListB). For each of these items, i will then replace the "searched value" by it's "replacement value".

```
//StringReplacer(SearchValue,ReplacementValue)
List<StringReplacer> ListB = new List<StringReplacer>(); 
ListB.Add(new StringReplacer("JAN", "24/01/2015"));
ListB.Add(new StringReplacer("FEB", "24/02/2015"));
ListB.Add(new StringReplacer("MAR", "24/03/2015"));
ListB.Add(new StringReplacer("APR", "24/04/2015"));


List<XLS2015> ListA = new List<XLS2015>();
ListA = db.XLS2015.Where(y => (ListB.Any(y.F20.Any(tt => tt.SearchValue.Contains)))).ToList();

ListA = db.XLS2015.Where(y => (ListB.Any(y.F20.Contains(tt => tt.Source)))).ToList();
```

I could do that with foreach but i think a linq statement would achieve that better.

I already achieved to do it when ListB`is`List`:

```
ListA = ListA.Where(c => (ListB.Any(c.F20.ToString().Contains))).ToList();
```

but i can't figure out how to deal with an attribute of the object...

As an extra question, Instead of searching values (`Any()`, `Contains()`), is there any function that may "`SearchAndReplace`" in one shot ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only select on DB side, and replace on .NET side. You can still do it in single LINQ query, but it will only partialy be executed on SQL.

You can try this:

```
// To make it easier to create sql query put all search string in array
string[] search = ListB.Select(b => b.Search).ToArray();

List<XLS2015> ListA = db.XLS2015
    .Where(a => search.Contains(a.F20))
    .AsEnumerable() // execute on server at this point, and do rest in C#

    .Join(ListB, a => a.F20, b => b.Search, (a, b) => new { A = a, B = b })
    .Select(x => {
        // do replacement
        x.A.F20 = x.A.F20.Replace(x.B.Search, x.B.Replacement);
        return x.A;
    })
    .ToList();
```